# SQL index, attribute order

Tags: sql

For this particular sql query:

```
select firstName
from students
where lastName = "john"
```

Is building a B+ tree index on (lastName, firstName) faster than building the index on (firstName, lastName) and why?

Comment: (lastName, firstName) will be better, because you have `WHERE` condition on `lastName` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX name (lastName,FirstName)` will be faster than `INDEX name (FirstName,lastName)`

It can also be used for queries that specify just a lastName value because that column is a **leftmost** prefix of the index

from [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you
>   have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
>   search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).